# Importing constants (function names) from external file

Tags: python, dictionary, rabbitmq, constants

This is the file structure:

```
root_dir/
├── analysis_tools
│   ├── analysis_tools.py
├── others
│   ├── constants.py
├── rabbit_wrappers
│   ├── rabbit_wrapper.py
└── utils
```

I am working on a workflow implemented using RabbitMq. This is the brief psuedo-code:
 1. Task added to RabbitMQ queue
 2. Autoscaler spins up Virtual Machine based on Queue
 3. Virtual Machine turns on and consumes from the queue

There is one type of machine per queue. So if there is a message in queue1, I need to run func1. If queue2, i need to run func2.

## **func[n] consumes from queue[n]**

```
from analysis_tools.analysis_tools import AnalysisTools

runner = AnalysisTools()

FUNCTION_MAP = {
    'func1' : runner.func1,
    'func2' : runner.func2
}
QUEUE_MAP = {
    'func1' : "queue1",
    'func2' : "queue2"
}
```

I have a function_map and a queue_map. I pass the function to run (func1/func2) in via command-line argument. Based on what function it's running, it automatically attaches and consumes from the relevant queue.

What I want to do save the `FUNCTION_MAP` and `QUEUE_MAP` inside `others/constants.py`. Then I want to be able to call thees functions in both `analysis_tools/analysis_tools.py` and `rabbit_wrappers/rabbit_wrapper.py`

The problem is when I keep my two `MAP`s in constants, it throws an error since it cannot find "runner", and I don't want to/probably shouldn't be instantiating an object of AnalysisTools in my `constants.py` file.

So basically, 2 questions.

**Q1. How can I save my function_map externally, and call it?**

I could call the runner from where I've called the function like so `runner.FUNCTION_MAP["func1"]()`

**Q2. How can I import the constants generally?**

This `from others.constants import *` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to create a circular dependancy. You want analysis_tools.py to depend on constants.py and constants.py on analysis_tools.py.

Having a file named constants is not generally a good idea. Things should live where they belong functionally, not according to type. You don't have a file call classes.py, functions.py, variables.py for the same reason you shouldn't have a file called constants.py.

FUNCTION_MAP is clearly related to AnalysisTools, just put it in the same file.

Re: Q2, you generally just import what you need in each module. If there are no circular dependencies you should have no problem doing that.

Comment: I do agree with you. However, constants has other constants as well, this is a minimum reproducible example. There are constants which are required by both analysis_tools and rabbit_wrapper. Currently, I have the same constants declared in both files (Which is quite messy, and bad practice) trying to make a central file for all my hardcoded values. But problems keep arising.

Comment: Problems keep arising because you are creating a new problem while trying to sort the other :) Decide which module depends on which one (child module depends on parent module), then declare the constants in the "parent" one, and import what you need from the "child" one